# Slideshow with video and images using Videojs and Flexslider

Tags: jquery, slideshow, flexslider

I'm using flexslider to play a slideshow on a webpage for a client. I would like one of the slides to be a video which should stop when the slide changes. I'm quite new with JS and JQuery. I tried several things but it is either the video keeps on playing while is not on focus or the slideshow stops working.

I have made this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RaulMv/d4Xvb/ using the source from this page http://www.briancribb.com/demo/flexslider_demos/test04.html

This is the script:
    "use strict";

```
var myPlayer;
var currentVidID;
var myVids = new Array();

$(document).ready(function() {  

$('.slides > li > video').each( function(i) {
    currentVidID = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log('ready(): currentVidID = ' + currentVidID);
    if (i==0) {
        videojs( currentVidID ).ready(function(){
            console.log("VideoJS is ready. First player.");
            myPlayer = this; // Initialized to the first player.
        });
    } else {
        videojs( currentVidID ).ready(function(){
            console.log("VideoJS is ready. Next player.");
        });
    }
});


$('#testSlider04').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",             //String: Select your animation type, "fade" or "slide"
    animationLoop: true,            //Boolean: Should the animation loop? If false, directionNav will received "disable" classes at either end
    slideshow: false,               //Boolean: Animate slider automatically
    slideshowSpeed: 7000,           //Integer: Set the speed of the slideshow cycling, in milliseconds
    animationSpeed: 600,            //Integer: Set the speed of animations, in milliseconds
    initDelay: 0,                   //{NEW} Integer: Set an initialization delay, in milliseconds
    randomize: false,               //Boolean: Randomize slide order
    before: function(){             //Callback: function(slider) - Fires asynchronously with each slider animation
        currentVidID = $('.flex-active-slide > .video-js').first().attr('id');
        myPlayer = videojs(currentVidID); // Setting to the currently viewed player. We might not be on the first video when this is called.
        if(!myPlayer.paused()) {
            myPlayer.pause();
            console.log(currentVidID + " is supposed to pause now.");
        }       
    }
});



});
```

Notice that it works on that page with several videos but not with videos and images.

Is there a way to make the video stops when the slide changes using video and images at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have already fixed the problem. I need it to create a function that actually stops the video before the next slide appears.

Here is the code:

```
var myPlayer = videojs("example_video_1");

$(document).ready(function() {  


$('#testSlider04').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",             //String: Select your animation type, "fade" or "slide"
    animationLoop: true,            //Boolean: Should the animation loop? If false, directionNav will received "disable" classes at either end
    slideshow: false,               //Boolean: Animate slider automatically
    slideshowSpeed: 7000,           //Integer: Set the speed of the slideshow cycling, in milliseconds
    animationSpeed: 600,            //Integer: Set the speed of animations, in milliseconds
    initDelay: 0,                   //{NEW} Integer: Set an initialization delay, in milliseconds
    randomize: false,               //Boolean: Randomize slide order
    before: function(){             //Callback: function(slider) - Fires asynchronously with each slider animation
       videojs("example_video_1").ready(function(){
       // EXAMPLE: Pause the video.
       myPlayer.pause();
       }); 
    }
});
});
```

Here is the working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RaulMv/4KtkL/

Comment: Why does this break if you add another video?